# Remove Duplicate Numbers in 2D Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array of number arrays like say

```
nonunique = [[1,2,3][2,3,4][1,5]];
```

I want a 1d array of all the unique keywords.

```
unique = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Existing solutions aim at matching the entire arrays rather than just returning a 1d array of numbers. Any shortcuts to this in vanilla javascript?

I tried this reduce function from stackoverflow but it seems to filter some non-duplicate values too.

```
unique = nonunique.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val.filter((e)=>acc.includes(val))));
```

It doesn't work properly and I can't figure out how to fix it. I also tried

```
unique = nonunique.filter(onlyUnique);
```

but filter(onlyUnique) doesn't seem to be available on firefox.

Comment: You should be using `!acc.includes(e)` (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwbuph50/))

Comment: Use sets. /thread

Comment: Use this:

`Array.from(new Set(nonunique.reduce(function (acc, val) { return acc.concat(val) }, [])));`